# What is the derivative $f(x) = -9 e^{x \sin x}$?

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) = -9 e^{x \sin x}$$

To find this derivative do I drop the sin x from the exponent first? and then if that is the case where do I go from there?

Comment: Chain rule first. Then product rule.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=-9e^{x \sin x}$

$f'(x)=-9e^{x\sin x}(x\sin x)'$

$f'(x)=-9e^{x\sin x}(1\cdot \sin x+ \cos (x)\cdot x)$

$f'(x)=-9e^{x\sin x}(\sin x+x\cos x)$

Comment: Now I do the product rule? and is there a product rule within a product rule?

Comment: Yes, now use the product rule: $h(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)\implies h'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)$. In this case $h(x)= x\cdot \sin x$.

Comment: How do I do g prime of x if thats essentially what im solving for in the first place?

Comment: In this case your $g(x)=\sin x$. The derivative of this is $g'(x)=\cos x$.

Comment: @user163689: I've edited it to the full answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use $\frac{d}{dx}ce^{f(x)} = cf'(x)e^{f(x)}$ where $c$ is your constant

Comment: Hi jake.toString, I did an edit with nice formatting, and correction of the error (missing derivative), and then you did an edit overwriting it. You may look at it and keep what you like.

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed that too and made the same correction :)

Comment: k. I also think it looks better readable with small space \, after the c's, like $\left( c\, {\mathrm e}^{\,f(x)} \right)' = c\, {\mathrm e}^{\,f(x)}\, f'(x)$, but that just as aside.